# Unir Tabelas SQL

Tags: sql

Tenho duas tabelas:

`curso`
`curso_configurar`

Com a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é: Eu preciso incluir dentro do `curso_configurar`, os cursos que serão configurados, até aí está OK. Porém, quando eu for adicionar uma nova configuração, não posso listar o curso que já foi configurado.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM (`curso`) LEFT JOIN `curso_configurar` ON `curso_configurar`.`cur_id`=`curso`.`cur_id` WHERE `curso_configurar`.`cur_id` NOT IN ('curso.cur_id') ORDER BY `cur_titulo` ASC
```

Neste caso, listo somente os cursos que já foram configurados, eu preciso fazer o inverso, listar os cursos que NÃO FORAM configurados.

Como eu posso montar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta selecionar os cursos que não possuem registro na tabela de configurações. Assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `curso` c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM `curso_configurar` cc
                 WHERE cc.cur_id = c.cur_id )
```

***Post Script:***

Assim como no tratamento de listas nas linguagens de programação, o SQL também oferece recursos mais eficientes para selecionar os dados e aplicar restrições sobre eles e esses recursos devem ser aproveitados para evitar problemas com performance no futuro.

No caso da consulta para *"selecionar os cursos que já foram configurados"* você deveria simplificá-la. Desse jeito:

```
SELECT * 
FROM curso c 
    JOIN curso_configurar cc ON cc.cur_id = c.cur_id 
ORDER BY c.cur_titulo ASC
```

A query que você escreveu com essa finalidade, se está funcionando é só por milagre.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma: https://pastebin.com/PdQV8Wj8

Comment: `php` parece grego para mim: Não sei quando você está executando, concatenando, declarando, obtendo o valor ou qualquer outra coisa.